# data gone missing when turning numeric into factor

Tags: r, na, factors

I imported an SPSS file into R using the package `memisc`

```
data <- as.data.set(spss.portable.file("C:/Users/...por")
```

returning the following structure

```
str(data)
Data set with 1937 obs. of 209 variables:
 $ swe1    : Nmnl. item w/ 4 labels for 1,2,3,... + ms.v.  num  3 2 1 4 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ swe2    : Nmnl. item w/ 4 labels for 1,2,3,... + ms.v.  num  3 3 2 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 ...
```

I want to perform a latent class analysis in poLCA and thus tried to convert into factors with positive integers using

```
swe1 <- factor(sample(1:1937, replace=TRUE), 
  levels=1:4, labels=c("Trifft gar nicht zu", "Trifft eher nicht zu", 
  "Trifft eher zu", "Trifft voll und ganz zu"))
```

Problem is, the data seems to go missing during this step. Except for some random values I only get NAs back (when repeating this step, it were different values that got returned, but still mostly NAs. Also defining the actual NAs won't help)

```
str(swe1)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "Trifft gar nicht zu",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably mention the external packages you've used too

Comment: Also, the problem with your code is you have many more unique levels than `4` (like you specified). Check `length(unique(sample(1:1937, replace=TRUE)))`

Comment: david, I had used 1:4 before and R returned the first 4 values of my data set, so I figured it had to include the total number of cases in my dataset. sorry, I am new to R.

Comment: When using `levels` and `labels` you'll have to set the correct number of unique values (which isn't 4 in your case) or else, everything become `NA` except that the first 4 unique vlaues

Comment: Ok, so labels is 4 in my case as this is the number of labels. just to be clear, unique values stands for? your code returned different numbers depending on whether I applied my code or not (before: [1] 1237, after: [1] 1229)

Comment: That's because `sample` resets a random seed each time you run it. If you want reproduce same results you have to use `set.seed` try doing `set.seed(123)` and then running my code, then run these two lines again

Comment: sorry, I feel awfully stupid right now, but it's still differing numbers after havong set the seed

Comment: No, it's not. Try: `set.seed(123);
length(unique(sample(1:1937, replace=TRUE)));
set.seed(123);
length(unique(sample(1:1937, replace=TRUE)))`

Comment: ok. where to go from there? I am lost

Comment: It's unclear what you trying to achieve. Why are you doing `sample(1:1937, replace=TRUE)` in the first place?

Comment: sorry, if I wasn't clear. 1937 is the number returned if I ask for nrow of my dataset.

Comment: Can't you just do something like: `data$swe1 <- factor(data$swe1, labels=c("Trifft gar nicht zu", "Trifft eher nicht zu", 
  "Trifft eher zu", "Trifft voll und ganz zu"))` ? Although I don't know how many unique values you actually have there

Comment: this gives me an Error saying invalid labels, lenghth 4 should be 1 or 5. (ungültige 'labels'; Länge 4 sollte 1 oder 5 sein)

Comment: I think I might be totally wrong in some basic understanding here. please correct me if there's something wrong in these thoughts: my number of labels equals the number of levels in my factor as it is in the original SPSS file, 4. and the number given in the sample brackets should equal the total number of cases given in the data set?

Comment: What's `class(data$swe1)` gives you?

Comment: > class(data$swe1)
[1] "double.item"
attr(,"package")
[1] "memisc"

Comment: I'm not familiar with that `class`. Try `data$swe1 <- as.character(unlist(data$swe1))` and then `unique(data$swe1)`

Comment: This will give me the 4 labels plus missings: [1] "Trifft eher zu"          "Trifft eher nicht zu"   
[3] "Trifft gar nicht zu"     "Trifft voll und ganz zu"
[5] "-77"  / NA (if missings are specified beforehand)

Comment: Can you run `factor` on it now? `data$swe1 <- factor(data$swe1, labels=c("Trifft gar nicht zu", "Trifft eher nicht zu", "Trifft eher zu", "Trifft voll und ganz zu"))` should work

Comment: yes! this seems to do the trick! thanks a lot for your help and patience, david!

Comment: The question is do the labels are matching the correct values

Comment: oh dear, thanks for staying on. no, they don't. The values seem to have randomly switched places

Comment: What does `unique(data$swe1)` gives you after you reload the data and run `data$swe1 <- as.character(unlist(data$swe1))`?

Comment: same as above :(  [1] "Trifft eher zu"          "Trifft eher nicht zu"   
[3] "Trifft gar nicht zu"     "Trifft voll und ganz zu"
[5] "-77"

Comment: So if you just do `data$swe1 <- factor(data$swe1)` it doesn't work?

Comment: using only these 2 commands seems to work.  data$swe5 <- as.character(unlist(data$swe5))
data$swe5 <- factor(data$swe5)

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. This should be fine then. How many column you need to turn to a `factor` class?

Comment: I got a huge data set, it's about 200 that need to be converted into factors

Comment: Ok, I'll post a quick solution for how to convert them all fast. Just tell me if you need to convert the whole data set or just certain columns, if the later is true, what are their names? like "swe1:200" or something like that?

Comment: some variables are of a different kind. these are the ones that should be represented as factors. they have different numbers of levels (and therefore different labels), though.the following are labelled as above-    swe1:10
academic
academ_1:9
acade_10:20

Comment: So how do you identify them? What are the names of the variables you want to convert to factor?

Comment: levels=1:2, labels=c('Ja', 'Nein')) apply for variables named leistung
leistu_1:8;

Comment: It really is a huge survey, with lots of differently coded factors. But if you give me an example, I can figure out how to copy it for the other variable types. I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Ok, if you install the `data.table` package using `install.packages("data.table")`, you could then replace all the column names `swe1, swe2, ..., swe200` using one line `librart(data.table); setDT(dat)[, paste0("swe", 1:200) := lapply(.SD, function(x) factor(as.character(unlist(x)))), .SDcols = paste0("swe", 1:200)]`

Comment: I installed the package and used library, but R can't find the function librart(data.table)

Comment: Sorry `library(data.table)` and use `data` instead of `dat`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out, David! Thanks to you I had a breakthrough with my problems regarding the LCA planned, today!